# Fullscreen modal in Materializecss

Tags: css, materialize

I want to have an fullscreen modal with an image and some buttons overlapping the image. I found this codepen, which shows how i want my modal to look like (width and height). The biggest Problem itself is the image for me. Since it either causes a scrollbar or , when responsive, is much smaller than the modal. Here is codepen i found, which shows how i want the modal.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/ThomasBurleson/full/EjrYgX/)

For the image i use:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

which is the `responsive-img` class from materialize.

How would i place an image inside this modal, so that it fills out the modal. And when i resize the window, the Image should stay **vertically** and **horizontally** aligned This should also be responsive. Any ideas?

Edit2: [my Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1eap8c3/197/)

Edit :

```
<div id="modal" class="modal blue-grey darken-4 "">
    <img class="responsive-img ">

    <div class="card-panel description ">
        <h4 class="white-text truncate ">Title</h4>
        <h6 class="white-text truncate ">Description</h6>
    </div>

    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-3 hoverable left-arrow ">
        <i class="icon-control material-icons medium ">chevron_left</i> 
    </a>
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-3 hoverable right-arrow ">
        <i class="icon-control material-icons medium ">chevron_right</i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-3 hoverable back-button ">
        <i class="icon-control material-icons medium ">clear</i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-3 hoverable pano-icon ">
        <i class="icon-control material-icons medium ">3d_rotation</i>
    </a>
    <div class="panel-loader-background">
        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active panel-loader">
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gap-patch">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-clipper right">
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will explain it. Inside my Modal i have a big Image, and some Components that are overlapping the Image. This means `card-panel description` is overlapping the image and also all the `btn-floating`.

However my goal is that the image is full `width` and full `height` but vertically and horizontally aligned(so when i resize, the image gets smaller, but the modal still keeps it full size). if u need more code, pls add a comment

Comment: What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing. It's not your own code  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I cant post much code here, since it is a very big project. But i will edit some things!

Comment: You can take a help in jsfiddle or sniper ,, or people make down vot

Comment: Added a fiddle. Is my question clear or should i provide a better explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the styling you want to achieve

https://jsfiddle.net/n1eap8c3/198/

added\

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

to

```
#modal{
    display:block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

and `left: 10%;` to `.left-arrow`
and `right: 10%;` to `.right-arrow`

Comment: almost. I want the modal to stay centered when resized and there should be no scrollbar, when make the window bigger. Could you update this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n1eap8c3/200/ to get rid of the scroll bar, just add `overflow: hidden;` as shown in the updated fiddle